# values not being passed between functions

Tags: javascript

I've been using javascript for years and am expanding my knowledge but dont understand the behaviour in the following code (simplified for brevity):

page.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        Modal.show('full', 'Hello World!');
});
```

Modal.js

```
class Modal {
     show({ type, title = '' }) {
        var builtModal = this.build(type, title)
        // do something
    }

    build({ type, title }) {
       // do something
    }
}
```

In Modal.show, type == 'full' & title is correct but in Modal.build (called from Modal.show) type == undefined & title == "". I'm expecting the values to be set as per the calling function... Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using destructuring in the parameter lists, you need to pass objects to be destructured:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    Modal.show({type: 'full', title: 'Hello World!');
});

class Modal {
    show({ type, title = '' }) {
        var builtModal = this.build({type, title})
        // do something
    }

    build({ type, title }) {
       // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: That's steered me in the right direction - part way through my code I'd changed from a number of parameters being passed into a function to passing in a complex object of the parameters values. Guess I'm used to stricter languages! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the function call you use two separate arguments. Try changing it to:

```
Modal.show({ type: 'full', title: 'Hello World!'});
```

Comment: Good catch, need to do the same on this.build(type, title) too